# Whitelisting IPs with .htaccess / .htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

Using the following `.htaccess`, I am able to successfully limit access to users with the correct username/password and users from a specific IP address:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter your password"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd

Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

Allow from 123.123.123.123
Satisfy Any
```

This works on a number of different servers, however, today I came across a server where this *doesn't* work 100%.  Users with the correct username/password *can* login, but users from the specified IP *are not* allowed and are forced to enter a password.

Is there something in `httpd.conf` that might be preventing the IP whitelist from working?  I've tried a number of variations and continue to get the same result.  All servers are Apache on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

To do the job and allow from IP without password prompt, and also allow from any address with password prompt, it work perfect like this :

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
AuthName "password please"
AuthUserFile /home/accountpath/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.1.1
Satisfy Any
```